# Al asignar un retorno de valores el cual devuelve 2 enteros, a 2 variables globales me sale: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python

Esta función definida debería devolver un dos enteros con los nombres "digNum" y "MXADIVINANZAS", pero al asignarlos al final del código a dos variables "digitosNum" y "MAXADIVINANAZAS" me da un error.

```
def elegirDificultad():
    dificultad = ''
    while dificultad not in '1 2 3 4'.split():
        print('¿Qué dificultad deseas jugar? (Fácil"1"/Normal"2"/Dificil"3"/Extremo"4") (escribe el número correspondiente)')
        dificultad = input()
        int(dificultad)
        if dificultad == 1:
            digNum = 3
            MXADIVINANZAS = 15
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS
        if dificultad == 2:
            digNum = 3
            MXADIVINANZAS = 10
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS

        if dificultad == 3:
            digNum = 4
            MXADIVINANZAS = 10
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS

        if dificultad == 4:
            digNum = 4
            MXADIVINANZAS = 5
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS

digitosNum, MAXADIVINANZAS = elegirDificultad()
```

Comment: Si no se cumple ninguno de los if, o la condición del while no se cumple, tu función retorna "nada", que es `None`, y es lo que causa el problema al tratar de asignarlo a dos variables.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error aquí:

```
    dificultad = input()
    print(dificultad)
    if dificultad == 1:
```

La variable `dificultad` contiene una cadena ("1") y la estas comparando contra un entero (1).

Se parecen, pero no son lo mismo.

Entonces, cuando intentas iterar por segunda vez, la expresión

```
dificultad not in '1 2 3 4'.split()
```

se reduce a

```
'1' not in ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

qué es `False`, por lo que se sale del `while` y se termina la función sin retornar ninguna valor, o sea, retorna `None`.

*Solución*

Lo más sano es cambiar todos los `if`, por

```
    dificultad = input()
    print(dificultad)
    if dificultad == "1":
```

¿Por qué no convertir la entrada a entero? Pues porque la entrada puede ser cualquier cosa, y si no es un entero, entonces se genera una excepción.

Comment: Pero después de "dificltad = input( )"  he puesto "int(dificultad)". ¿Esto es correcto?